# The value of a harmonic function in the interior of a unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

> > Let $u(z)$ be a bounded harmonic function in $D$ such that the limit
> >     $$\lim_{r→1^-}u(re^{iφ})$$
> >     is equal to 1 when for $0 < φ < π$ and to 0 for $π < φ < 2π$. Find $u(1/2)$.

To solve this problem, I want to show by approximation that 
$$u(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \lim_{r→1^-}u(re^{iφ}) \frac{\frac{3}{4}}{1- \cos (\theta) +\frac{1}{4}} \, d\theta.$$
And by the hypothesis, the equation above is equal to $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \frac{\frac{3}{4}}{1- \cos (\theta) +\frac{1}{4}} \, d\theta$.

I have trouble in the rigorous proof. I have tried the dominated convergence theorem but I don't know what is that dominating function(since this is a problem in complex analysis, I think there should be a way to avoid using results in real analysis). Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Bounded Convergence Theorem is more appropriate in this case because the functions on concentric circles are uniformly bounded and converge pointwise a.e. to the boundary function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Poisson integral formula* giving the value $u\bigl(r,\phi)$ when $u$ is given on a boundary circle of radius $R$ reads as follows (see 3.1-4 on page 2 of [this document](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/lpde/lpde301.pdf)):
$$u(r e^{i\phi})={1\over2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}u(Re^{i\psi}){R^2-r^2\over r^2-2Rr\cos(\phi-\psi)+R^2}\>d\psi\qquad(0\leq r\leq R)\ .$$
You have referred to this formula in the special case $R=1$. In particular you have
$$ u\left({1\over2}\right)={1\over2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}u(Re^{i\psi}){R^2-{1\over4}\over {1\over4}-R\cos\psi+R^2}\>d\psi\qquad\left(R>{1\over2}\right)\ ,\tag{1}$$
whereby $u$ is a smooth function of $\psi$ as long as $R<1$, and the kernel part is bounded as long as $R$ stays away from ${1\over2}$.
Now let $R\to1-$ in $(1)$, and use the dominated convergence theorem. The end result will of course be what you have found out already.

Comment: Could you please show me which version of "Poisson formula"  you are using? I don't know any Poisson formulas without assuming the continuity of the function on the boundary. In this problem, $u$ can't be extended to a continuous function on the closed unit disk.

Answer (score -1):

In the book 'Complex Analysis' by Lars V. Ahlfors 2nd Edition 1966 on pages 167-8 there is a theorem (Theorem 25) that states: Given a piecewise continuous function U(theta) 0 <= theta <= 2pi on the unit circle z = exp(i*theta), then integrating the integrand

```
(1/2pi)*U(theta)*Re( (exp(i*theta)+z)/(exp(i*theta)-z) )
```

around the unit circle wrt theta for any given z inside the unit circle gives a function Pu(z) say, which is harmonic for |z| < 1 (eg. z=1/2) and whose limit at any point at the boundary where U is continuous is the corresponding value of U.

The theorem above, for which the book provides a rigorous proof, follows a section on pages 165-6 on Poisson's formula, which is the basis of the formula given in the original question. The book requires a sophisticated understanding of functions of a complex variable but the statement of the theorem above is very clear and does not demand continuity of the boundary function U, which is where the question was left.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).